# How to get Variable from different PHP-Code part

Tags: php, mysql, variables, global-variables

i'm making a website for a school project and have problems with getting the variable i need to execute a mysql query.In line 171 the $username variable is undefiend but it's still the same index.php file so i don't understand why i can't use it(`$ch_query=mysql_query("update benutzer set password='$neues_psw' where benutzer_name='$username'");`).Even my teacher can't help me so i thought maybe somebody could take a look at my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['visited']=false;
require_once ('../php/dblink.php');     
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "logo">

    </div>

    <div id = "header">

    </div>

    <div id = "login">
        <?php
        $rConn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , '');
require_once ('../php/dblink.php');
if((false === is_resource($rConn)) || (false === mysql_select_db('accounts', $rConn)))
{
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['benutzername']) && !empty ($_POST['passwort']))
    {

    mysql_select_db("accounts");    
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['benutzername']);    
    $pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwort']); 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM benutzer where benutzer_name='$username'and password = '$pw' LIMIT 1");
        if(!$result)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                if ($row['benutzer_name']==$username && $row['password']==$pw)
            {
                echo"login erfolgreich !!!";

                echo"Willkommen";
                echo" ";
                echo"$username";
                $_SESSION['visited']=true;

                    echo $row['benutzer_name'];

            }
            else
            {
                echo"falsche daten";
                $_SESSION['visited']=false;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo"bitte Benutzernamen und Passwort eingeben !";
    }
}
?>

        <?php
            echo "<form method='post'>";
            if ($_SESSION['visited']==true)
            {
                echo "<center><button type='submit' name='Logout'>Auslogen</button></center>";
                IF(isset($_POST['Logout']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['visited']=false;
                    session_destroy();

                }
            }
            else{
            ?>

   <form method='post'>

        <label>Benutzername:</label> <input type='text' name='benutzername' /><br />
        <label>Vorname:</label> <input type='text' name='vorname' /><br />
        <label>Passwort:</label> <input type='password' name='passwort' /><br />

        <input type='submit' name='speichern' value='Registrieren' />
       </form>

       <form method='post' action="../html/index.php">

        <label>Benutzername:</label> <input type='text' name='benutzername' /><br />
        <label>Passwort:</label> <input type='password' name='passwort' /><br />

        <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' />

    </form>
    <?php
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['speichern']  ) )
    {

        $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
        $benutzername = $_POST['benutzername'];
        $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

        // $sql = 'UPDATE person SET name="'.$name.'" WHERE benutzername="1"';
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO benutzer (benutzer_name, vorname, password)
        VALUES (
        "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $benutzername).'", 
        "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $vorname).'", 
        "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $passwort).'"
        )';

        $db_erg = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
        $error_meld = mysqli_error($db_link);       
        $dublikat = strpos($error_meld, "Duplicate") !== false;

        if($db_erg == 1)
        {
            echo "<span style='color:darkgreen;'>Neuer Benutzer ".$benutzername." angelegt!</span>";
        } 
        else
        {
            if($dublikat)
                echo "<span style='color:darkred;'>".$benutzername." ist schon vorhanden!</span>";              
            else
                echo "<span style='color:darkred;'>Fehler!</span>";
        }   
    }
    ?>

    </div>


    <div id = "links_mid">

    </div>

    <div id = "rechts_mid">

    </div>

    <div id = "textarea">

    <?php
        echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION);print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';

        if ($_SESSION['visited']==true) // Hier ist Content für Leute die eingeloggt sind !
            {

                 echo"<form action='?aendern=1' method='post'>";

        echo"<label>Passwort Ändern :</label> <input type='password' name='new_pw' /><br />";

        echo"<input type='submit' name='change' value='aendern' />";
        echo"</form>";

            }
            IF(isset($_POST['change']))
        {
        $neues_psw = $_POST['new_pw'];

        $ch_query=mysql_query("update benutzer set password='$neues_psw' where benutzer_name='$username'");
        $db_erg = mysqli_query( $db_link , $ch_query );

        if(! $db_erg)
        {
        die(mysql_error());
        }else
        {
        echo"Passwort wurde geändert";
        }

        }
            ?>


    </div>
    <div id = "footer">
    <address>
    test 
    </address>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rule of thump: a function should be not longer than a single screen height, if you can prevent it. your code is really hard to follow in its current state.

Comment: Apart from that: you are using the old, outdated and long since deprecated `mysql` extension. You want to switch over to the modern `mysqli` or `PDO` extension instead so that your code will not stop working the moment you upgrade php. Also read and learn about the benefits of using "prepared statements" and "parameter binding", which removes the need for that manual escaping which you currently do.

Comment: Then: one _never_ stores a password in a database. Not in clear text and not "encrypted". What you store is a _hash_ of a password. Then, at authentication time you again hash the provided login password and compare both _hashes_, not the passwords. That way you do not compromise your users account even if someone gains hold of your database details.

Comment: Further you have a passage where you cite a client side provided string (`$neues_psw = $_POST['new_pw'];`) directly in a query without any protection. That opens your code to sql injection attacks. As mentioned before, Using "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" is the only option to cure that reliably. All those calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` are _not_ a secure alternative.

Comment: Coming back to your question: it is hard to see with "spagetti code" like that, but it appears as if you only define `$username` under certain conditions. Maybe that is why it is not present? But as said: restructuring your code into separate units will make it _much_ easier to understand it. For example: extract specific functions performing certain tasks with the users table: inserting, updating, removing. That makes your main code much shorter and easier to read and understand.

Comment: Hey , wow thanks for the fast answer. i try to follow your tips to make the code better :)

Comment: There's a lot of  "echo"s without space. As in: echo"login erfolgreich !!!";
                echo"Willkommen";
                echo" ";
                echo"$username";
Try fixing that first (adding a space between echo and the string).

Answer (score -1):

Before you transition to making a site that contains real users' data, it's important that you replace your mysql queries with mysqli or PDO prepared statements. ([Hints on how to prevent SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html))

Three things need to happen for your `$username` variable to be set in the first place:

1. `isset($_POST['login'])` must be true. (User gets to this page by clicking the Login button.)
2. `!empty($_POST['benutzername'])` must be true. (User must have entered something in the `name="benutzername"` input field of the form.)
3. `!empty($_POST['benutzername'])` must be true. (See #2 above.)

I recommend [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for further reading.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It only cites a few obvious facts, but does not solve the question. So it should have been a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right. I'm a high school computer science teacher. This question triggered my teach-to-fish-rather-than-give-fish approach.

Comment: Well, you have got all time to edit your question and add the precise solution! ;-)